# jquery sequence fadeOut and then remove

Tags: jquery

I try `$('somediv').fadeOut.remove();`
but it only remove it, bang... it dont wait for the nice fadeOut, and THEN remove

why.. how to respect fadeout, and then remove..

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use a callback:

```
$('somediv').fadeOut( function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

The code in the callback function you're passing to [`fadeOut()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) will not execute until the animation is complete.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/p2LWE/

An alternative would be to [`queue()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) the [`remove()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) , but I think the callback is better.

```
$('somediv').fadeOut()
            .queue(function(nxt) { 
                $(this).remove();
                nxt();
            });
```

Comment: and where would you add the "slow" parameter for "remove" ?

Comment: @armen: $('somediv').fadeOut('slow', function() { $(this).remove(); });

Answer (score 9):

Here is the simple way,

```
$('#somediv').fadeOut(300,function(){ $(this).remove(); })};
```

or

```
$('#somediv').fadeOut("slow",function(){ $(this).remove(); })};
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery chaining, one part of the chain doesn't wait for other parts to end if there's a time-based component.  So when you want something to happen when another thing finishes, you'll need to use callbacks.  In this case, you call `fadeOut()` with a parameter for what function to run when it's done.  Like so:

`$('#somediv').fadeOut(function(){ $(this).remove(); })};`

So when `fadeOut()` is done (and you can add a leading parameter that dictates how long that'll take, either in miliseconds or 'fast', 'normal', or 'slow'), it'll call the function, which does the `remove()`.