# Use fadeIn when attribute has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, togglebutton

When I click on the toggle button, it changes the style attribute of the element from display none to block. Now, when this happens, I want to animate the left position of the menu. I have code like this, but works buggy and also, when it should go back to the right, it appears on the left..

```
var toggled = false;
$(toggleBtn).click(function() {
    toggled = !toggled;
    $(collapse).attr("style", toggled ? 'display:block !important' : 'display:none !important');
    if (collapse.attr('style', 'display:block !important')) {
        $(collapse).animate({left:'10%'});
    } else {
        $(collapse).animate({left:'100%'});
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please share your HTML also

Comment: Can you please share html and css you have used  , it will help to check the actual issue.

Comment: Relevant to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811303/jquery-sequence-fadeout-and-then-remove/14064830#14064830

Comment: As @YogeshSharma already said, include your HTML, and add an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). First guess is that it's buggy because `display` cannot be animated and simply changes while your animation takes time and that makes it look buggy.

Comment: yes, the display was the problem, thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this more as:

```
var toggled = false;
$(toggleBtn).click(function() {
    toggled = !toggled;
    $(collapse).toggle(toggled)
               .animate({ left: $(collapse).is(':visible') ? '10%' : '100%' });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

change the condition

```
 if (collapse.attr('style', 'display:block !important'))
```

with the following

```
if (collapse.attr('style')=='display:block !important')
```

Comment: It would be better to use `is(':visible')`

Comment: yep. thats true. try to use `if(collapse.is(':visible'))`.